# Почему не работает bot.register_next_step_handler? Помогите 

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: call.data == 'work')
def process_callback_work(call):
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text = 'Напишите ID заявки, которую взяли в работу!')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, operator)

def operator(message):
    ans = message.text
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id_application, status FROM application""")
    if ans == cursor.fetchone()['id_application'] and cursor.fetchone()['status'] == 0:
        bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, 'Хорошо, напишите ответ на заявку')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_question)
    else:
        bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, 'Такой заявки не существует, либо же она взята в работу! Напишите ID заявки заново!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, operator)
```

После первого вызова `register_next_step_handler`, бот отсылает сообщение пользователю с просьбой ответить на него, но, когда пользователь отвечает на него, то ничего не происходит((((

Comment: Первый register_next_step_handler не работает((((

Comment: А вы проверяли что условие выполняется корректно?

Comment: А зачем call.message в register_next_step_handler?